# How conversation scope in implemented in CDI?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi

It is done through some session key that holds some structure?

Answer (score 2):

CDI is a specification, so the conversation scope is only specified, not implemented. Different implementors may decide on different strategies. Currently there are three - Weld, OpenWebBeans and CanDI. I don't know how it is implemented, but there aren't many ways - using the session in some way is most likely.

[see this tutorial](http://www.theserverside.com/tip/Dependency-Injection-in-Java-EE-6-Conversations-Part-4)

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use portable CDI extensions like MyFaces CODI!